# Shutdown Spring Boot application running on random port

Tags: spring-boot, netflix

I have a Spring Boot services and I manage deployment on the server using a batch script. So, when ever I have to deploy a update I shutdown current running service using Spring Boot's shutdown hook. For example:

```
curl -X POST http://%HOST_NAME%:%PORT%/actuator/shutdown
```

Here I am giving `%PORT%` number of the service, Which is same as I have given in `application.yml`. I don't want hardcode the port neither in `application.yml` nor want to pass from the command line while starting the Spring Boot application. Actually I do not want to mention the port. I just want Spring Boot use any of the random port available on the server. If I will do the same then how can I shut down the service because I don't know the port where the service is running.

Comment: Though I can check  those ports in my Eureka discovery. but every time it will change (Random port) and I do not want to change every time in my script. 
I do not want to check my available ports on the server for each of my new service thats why want to use random port.
Any clue to handle this situation?

Comment: Where are your services deployed?

Comment: On windows server for now.